# How to retrieve the colleague's calendar name shared with my google calendar through google calendar API in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve the colleague's calendar name by using the code as follows, but it doesn't work.
code:

```
$calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry)
{
    print_r($calendarListEntry);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your authentication SCOPE is Calendar:

```
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
));
```

Secondly, you should use the example snippets provided by Google on every feature documentation. Calendar List [Source](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)